# What is the basin of attraction for the attracting fixed point $x_-$ of $f(x) = x^2+c$

Tags: recursion, chaos-theory

Attempt: If $x_-^2+c=x_-$ then $x_-=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-4c}}{2}$ which is attracting for $|f(x)|<1$ i.e $-2<c<\dfrac14$. How do I find the set of points $x$ such that the orbit $f^n(x) \to x_-$ (where $f^n(x)$ is $f$ applied $n$ times)?

Comment: Is $x$ real or complex?

Comment: assume x is real

Comment: Have you done any specific iterations with initial points chosen in $(-2,1/4)$? That would show some effort...

Comment: We're supposed to find an uncountable set

Comment: @Jeffrey That's ok, we're not looking for an uncountable amount of effort shown, but positive would be nice :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these $c$, the basin of attraction in the complex plane is a connected filled Julia set and so the basin of attraction in the real line is an interval.

One of the extremes of this interval is the other fixed point, the repelling fixed point $x_+$. The other extreme is sent to this fixed point by $f$; it is easily seen that this point is $-x_+$.

Comment: I'm not sure that an jump to the Julia set in the complex plane is a good idea here. The intersection between a connected filled Julia set and the real line need not be an interval. I'm aware, of course, that the Julia sets with an attractive fixed point are rather special but their boundary can be quite complicated. On the other hand, it's pretty easy to see that the open interval $-x_{+}<x<x_{+}$ is the basin of attraction by looking at the real graphs of $y=x^2+c$ and $y=x$ together.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, you're right of course.